# PHP/HTML form submit is not working

Tags: php, forms, netbeans

I'm unable to get my form to submit. I'm using PHP 5.6.24 and NetBeans 8.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

filename: index.php

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'password');

    //process log in stuff here

    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;

}

//LOG OUT
if(isset($_POST['logout_submit'])){
    session_destroy();
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
        unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
    //process additional log out stuff here
}

?>
```

HTML:

```html
<h4>Dashboard</h4>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
 <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) : ?>
 <label>Email: </label><br />
 <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="you@youremail.com"/><br />
 <label>Password: </label><br />
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your secret code"/><br />
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Log in" name="login_submit" />
 <?php else : ?>
 <input type="submit" value="Log out" name="logout_submit" />
 <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

What happens:

1. I set breakpoints at `session_start();` and at `if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){`
   and run in debug mode.
2. The code stops at the breakpoints on startup as expected.
3. I enter the email and pwd and click the Log In button.
4. Nothing happens; the first breakpoint is not even reached. No errors, warnings, or notices are displayed.

I've tried using
 `if($_POST['login_submit']){`
 `if($_POST['login_submit'] == "Log in"){`
 `if(filter_input(INPUT_POST,'login_submit')){`
but none of these have worked. I also created a new page with a form that gets a file (`<input type="file" name="datafile">`). The file picker dialog opens, but the Submit button does not submit on that page either.

For the fun of it, I copied the HTML output for the file (view source, ctrl+a, ctrl+c) and pasted it into Dreamweaver, then saved as an HTML file. When I opened that file in the browser and typed username/pwd and clicked Log In, it opened the index.php file as expected.

I thought, "maybe my breakpoints are broken (even though they work when the page is initially loaded)", so I stuck in some calls to a writeLogEntry function, to see what lines execute. When the login button is clicked, no additional messages were written.

What's so strange is that I have another (completed) PHP project in NetBeans whose login/logout code works perfectly fine. I used the same code snippets for the login form and processing in this new project and yet, I hit this brick wall. Any ideas on what to try? TIA.

Comment: I think you removed parts of your code we actually need to help you

Comment: `//process log in stuff here` that's the most relevant part of your code. And you seem to be adding `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;` regardless of the result of your validation?

Comment: You also seem to be having a logical error, where as `if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) :` will only be true if the user is already signed in.

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems I left out a critical `!` in the HTML part of the code -- my actual file says `<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) : ?>`

The processing code within the `if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){` block is missing because I haven't written it yet. :) I've just been trying to get into the if block.

Comment: Provided the session actually starts, that code does work. Depends on what you actually do with that `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: To make sure, I changed the opening PHP code to: `if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
    $bSessionStarted = session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

var_dump($_POST, $_SESSION, $bSessionStarted);
exit;'

and the `$bSessionStarted` is true. Still, the login_submit button doesn't do anything.

Comment: What is your print_r($_POST)?

Comment: Placing `print_r($_POST);` above the `if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){` line results in **Array ( )**. Placing it within the `if(isset($_POST['login_submit'])){ }` block yields nothing, because clicking the Log In button doesn't run any of the code.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Problem Solved

In a fit of frustration, I created a new project with the absolute bare minimum code -- no logout_submit button, no if statement for handling the click. Ran it and it worked. Added the logout_submit button and code, and that's now working too. Curious, I copied all the code and pasted it into my original project, and it's now working too.

It turns out, I had some PHP code **below** the form that was causing the problem but not generating an error. Once I removed it, the form worked like a charm.

Thanks to all who helped!